# Is there any way to make data corruption intentionally in python3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm now making an application which basically corrupts the data. That's what it does. However, I cannot find ways to save the corrupted data into a variable. I want the corrupted data saved in a python list like "holder=[]" to make them accessible later. Is there any way to do that?

```
import random
import time
import threading


def example():
    for counter in range(10):
        print(counter)


def thread_set_1():
    thread1=threading.Thread(target=example)
    thread2=threading.Thread(target=example)
    thread3=threading.Thread(target=example)
    thread4=threading.Thread(target=example)
    thread5=threading.Thread(target=example)
    thread6=threading.Thread(target=example)
    thread7=threading.Thread(target=example)
    thread8=threading.Thread(target=example)
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread3.start()
    thread4.start()
    thread5.start()
    thread6.start()
    thread7.start()
    thread8.start()

def thread_set_2():
    thread1=threading.Thread(target=thread_set_1)
    thread2=threading.Thread(target=thread_set_1)
    thread3=threading.Thread(target=thread_set_1)
    thread4=threading.Thread(target=thread_set_1)
    thread5=threading.Thread(target=thread_set_1)
    thread6=threading.Thread(target=thread_set_1)
    thread7=threading.Thread(target=thread_set_1)
    thread8=threading.Thread(target=thread_set_1)
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread3.start()
    thread4.start()
    thread5.start()
    thread6.start()
    thread7.start()
    thread8.start()
```

Comment: Do you have any idea to check wether the data is corrupted?

Comment: Actually, what I want to make is random number generator. Not pseudo random, but 'True Randomness' using python. I'm pretty sure that if I can get the corrupted data as a list, remove None values, and shuffle it tens of times, the data will be quite random. Therefore, anything unpredictable is 'corrupted data' I want to get

Comment: This isn't random. You're using the thread scheduling algorithm to generate numbers, which is quite predictable. With almost no exception, my computer prints out '0123456789' many times over.

Comment: Oh... I didn't know that. Could you explain more about it???

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to save your output? I think that this won't be possible using a simple array, as the global interpreter lock is going to prevent simultaneous access by multiple threads to a global variable. However, if you write your output to a file, this will work. If you change your function `example` like so:

```
def example():
    for counter in range(10):
        with open('testfile.txt','a') as fid:
            fid.write(str(counter))
```

and then run:

```
open('testfile.txt','w') #create empty file
thread_set_1()
thread_set_2()
```

`testfile.txt` will contain seemingly random numbers. However, this is going to be very slow, as the file is going to be opened and closed every time a number is written.

The main reason to not use this procedure to create random numbers is that they are not going to be truly random, as the numbers written to the file are going to increase with time. You wrote that you plan on shuffling the numbers afterwards; if you plan on using `random` for this (it is among your imports), why do you want to additionally create your own random number generator?